# Sort list in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, sorting

I have the following class Linea

```
class Linea
   include Comparable
   attr_accessor :maxcap, :capatuale, :citta1, :citta2, :lineac

   def initialize(c1, c2, maxc)
      raise CapacitaIllegale if maxc <= 0
      @maxcap = maxc
      @capatuale = maxc
      @citta1 = c1
      @citta2 = c2
      @lineac = []
      @lineac.push(c1)
      @lineac << c2
   end

    def <=> (l)
      if(l.is_a?(Linea))
        if (l.maxcap>@maxcap)
          return l.maxcap
        end
        if(l.maxcap==@maxcap)
          if (l.citta1.pop + l.citta2.pop>@citta1.pop+@citta2.pop)
            return l.maxcap
          end
        end
      end
      return -1
    end
  end
```

after in the class Rete where I want to insert the Linea and do the sort using <=> so;

```
  class Rete
     attr_accessor :lineec, :guasto_seg

     def initialize()
      @rete = []
      @guasto_seg = []
     end

     def aggiungi_linea(c1, c2, maxc)
        l = Linea.new(c1, c2, maxc)
        unless (citta_presente(c1, c2))
           @rete << l
           @rete.sort { |l1,l2| l1<=>l2 if l1.is_a?(Linea) and l2.is_a?(Linea) }
        else
           raise LineaGiaEsistente
        end
     end

     + some diferent method   

  end
```

I wanted to ask for explanations of how it is used for sort if mine is right is if <=> is done and called into the sort so right.???????
please give me an answer as soon as possible, thanks.

Comment: You may want to read the documentation on this: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort

Answer (score 2):

To be useful for sorting, the `<=>` method must behave like this:

```
big_linea <=> small_linea #=> 1
big_linea <=> equally_big_linea #=> 0
small_linea <=> big_linea #=> -1
```

When that works, you should be able to do

```
@rete.sort #no block needed
```